# Feathersjs link or unlink existing account (accessToken) oauth login

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, facebook-login, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

Is there a way to link or unlink existing account (accessToken) oauth login to feathersjs

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the [account linking API documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/oauth.html#account-linking) and can be done by sending the existing access token in the `feathers_token` query parameter:

```js
<a href="/oauth/github?feathers_token=<your access token>">
  Login with GitHub
</a>
```

To unlink and account you would set the `<name>Id` property on the user to `null`.

Comment: I using feathersjs for mobile api, it is also the same for that?

Comment: For mobile you can set your existing access token in the `Authenticate` header when making the call to `/authenticate` with the provider access token.

Comment: Hi @Daff, what do you mean by provider access token?